# dynamodb get all items by an array of ids

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table with an attribute with name id and of type HASH. I want to get all items from a array of id's.

```
{
    TableName: `MyTable`,
    FilterExpression: 'id IN (:id)',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':id': ids },
};
```

What should I do to get all items by my ids?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You can also use `DocumentClient` and `batchGet`.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

let queryParams = {RequestItems: {}};
queryParams.RequestItems['tableName'] = {
  Keys: [{'id': 'Value1'}, {'id': 'value2'}],
  ProjectionExpression: 'id' //define other fileds that you have Ex: 'id,name'
};

documentClient.batchGet(queryParams, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('failure:getItemByBatch data from Dynamo error', err);
  } else {
    console.log('success:getItemByBatch data from Dynamo data');
    console.log(data)
  }
});
```

Comment: Doesnt work with Typescript strick checking. It returns `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"tableName"' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  Property 'tableName' does not exist on type '{}'`

Comment: Its this code. Possibly because I have `"strict": true` in `tsconfig.json`. The work around I found is to do `(queryParams as any).`

Comment: @Tanuki that's an error that depends on your TS config. It's irrelevant to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please use `BatchGetItem` API to get multiple values from DynamoDB table.

[BatchGetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#batchGetItem-property)

**Example:-**

```
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({maxRetries: 5, retryDelayOptions: {base: 300} });

var table = "Movies";

var year_val = 2015;
var title = "The Big New Movie";

var params = {
    "RequestItems" : {
        "Movies" : {
            "Keys" : [ {
                "yearkey" : {N : "2016"},
                "title" : {S : "The Big New Movie 1"}
            } ]
        }
    },
    "ReturnConsumedCapacity" : "TOTAL"
};

dynamodb.batchGetItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to get item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err,
                null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Movie data:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

Comment: I get a 'Invalid attribute value type' error. Changed the params object to this: {
    "RequestItems" : {
        "MyTable" : {
            "Keys" : [ {
                "id" : {S : "f403f77e-8c18-4ed5-94bb-c4b5f14d1b01"}
            }]
        }
    },
    "ReturnConsumedCapacity" : "TOTAL"
}

Answer (score 0):

Its in C#, below code is to get all items by an array of ids from a dynamodb table having different guid's using BatchGet or CreateBatchGet

```
        string tablename = "AnyTableName"; //table whose data you want to fetch

        var BatchRead = ABCContext.Context.CreateBatchGet<ABCTable>(  

            new DynamoDBOperationConfig
            {
                OverrideTableName = tablename; 
            });

        foreach(string Id in IdList) // in case you are taking string from input
        {
            Guid objGuid = Guid.Parse(Id); //parsing string to guid
            BatchRead.AddKey(objGuid);
        }

        await BatchRead.ExecuteAsync();
        var result = BatchRead.Results;
```

// ABCTable is the table modal which is used to create in dynamodb & data you want to fetch